# After 15 mins Background Location update is not working in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, background, gps, location

I have implemented background location update in ios based on the timer (like every 1 min). Its working good and getting location(lat and Long values) but after 15 it is disconnecting.
I'm not able to trigger it anymore. 
Can any one please help me out.

This is my code..

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    [[GlobalClass sharedGlobals].locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8) {
        [[GlobalClass sharedGlobals].locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    [[GlobalClass sharedGlobals].locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

    int timeInterval = 60; // (i.e., 1 mins )

    if (!setTimer) {
        setTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeInterval target: self
                                                  selector: @selector(toMakeServerCall) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Send Current lat & long to the server

- (void)toMakeServerCall {

    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[GlobalClass sharedGlobals] currentLocationObject].coordinate.latitude];
    NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[GlobalClass sharedGlobals] currentLocationObject].coordinate.longitude];

    NSLog(@"Current Lat is :%@ \n Current Long is :%@ ",latitude,longitude);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:www.google.com/myLatitude is: %@ and My Longitude is: %@",latitude,longitude]];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please refer my answer on below URL. may be it'll help you. [Location URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40887605/1728580)

Answer (score 1):

When you use "significant change" service (or frankly any location services), you don't use a timer. The OS calls *you* when there's a change in location, not the other way around.

Regarding your timer, when the app is suspended, the timer won't run any more. So, don't use a timer. But with significant change service, when the device detects that it has been moved a significant distance, your app will we awaken and be informed. As the [*Location and Maps Programming Guide: Starting the Significant-Change Location Service*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW8) says:

> If you leave the significant-change location service running and your iOS app is subsequently suspended or terminated, the service automatically wakes up your app when new location data arrives. At wake-up time, the app is put into the background and you are given a small amount of time (around 10 seconds) to manually restart location services and process the location data. (You must manually restart location services in the background before any pending location updates can be delivered, as described in [Knowing When to Start Location Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW16).) Because your app is in the background, it must do minimal work and avoid any tasks (such as querying the network) that might prevent it from returning before the allocated time expires. If it does not, your app will be terminated. If an iOS app needs more time to process the location data, it can request more background execution time using the [`beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1623051-beginbackgroundtaskwithname) method of the `UIApplication` class.

Comment: But still the app wont be running every minute. Significant location changes updates about a couple of times max in 10 to 15 mins even if there is a significant location update. Is there any other way to keep running the app in background and updating the location to my server every second? Like if I want to track precisely the route a car takes by updating its location on my server.

Comment: First, significant change won't practically change every second because, in my experience, the amount of distance you have to travel to achieve is so great (e.g. not meters, but rather kilometers). If you want constant updates as the car moves, you have to (a) register for background navigation mode in the capabilities screen; and (b) then use standard location services. But, again, you don't use timers with location services. Location services tells you when enough distance has been traversed to trigger a location update.

Comment: Thanks @Rob. My actual requirement is, I need to update the location during background/app terminated state with dynamic time interval like(1hr, 1day, 3day, etc.,). In that case, what I need to do?. If possible, Can you please share any sample code?

Comment: iOS places very strict constraints on the nature of background operations we can perform (all in a well-intended effort to avoid having tons of apps doing stuff in the background, draining our batteries, adversely affecting performance, in the process). But there are mechanisms ranging from significant change service (your app is awaken when there is a significant change in location, but you don't control when this happens), background fetch (where the OS will opportunistically check a server for available data), and full-blown background mode (limited to VoIP, music, true nav apps, etc.).

Comment: So, if your app is not a true nav app (i.e. it's primary purpose is for navigating while you drive around), you're limited to things like significant change service. And this doesn't fire according to some fixed schedule of "every x minutes/hours/etc." but rather ony when it detects that some significant location change has taken place (triggered by change in cell towers, IIRC, it probably considers whether the app is plugged in and the like, too).

Comment: about: "You must manually restart location services in the background before" I read the documents. I understand that if it ever triggers a **launch** then I need to reinstantiate my singleton locationManager. however if app was kept in background or only suspended and not terminated then I don't need to do anything? cuz I won't be getting the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey`, rather a normal callback right?

Answer (score 0):

Location updates may be paused even if you set `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` to false. The good thing is that you can get notified when the updates are paused, so you can restart location updates.

Define `locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates` in your `CLLocationManagerDelegate` like this:

```
func locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```