# ios Location Background Mode : Update location upto 18 mins only

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, gps, core-location

I have enabled Location background mode and added `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`.

After calling

```
[locationManger startUpdatingLocation];
```

After placing the application in background (by tapping home button), i can see location-services indicator been added to status bar.
After around 18 mins, the location-services indicator went away and app doesn't get any gps points.

NOTE:  `requestAlwaysAuthorization` is in place and granted.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Vinay: App will move on suspended mode that's why you'll not get the location after 18 min.  Please check below URL. it'll help you to get location more then 18 min. even app is in suspended mode.

[Go to this link](https://github.com/voyage11/Location)